# lightweight search engine for asp.net

Tags: c#, .net, search-engine, umbraco

I'm looking to develop a CMS project based on UMBRACO but I also need to index the documents created and to offer  search functionality therefore I would like to know if you have any suggestion for a lightweight search engine available in .net technology. The main requirement is to be simple and efficient (nothing complex like solr or sphinx ).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only need to search documents/nodes created in umbraco you can use xsltsearch perhaps? It's very easy to deploy.

Comment: +1 for light weight, 3 minute install :) Also worth of a mention although more heavy weight is FarmCode's "Examine" http://farmcode.org/page/Umbraco-Examine.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at [Lucene.net](http://incubator.apache.org/lucene.net/).

Comment: as I said "The main requirement is to be simple and efficient (nothing complex like solr or sphinx)". I think that lucene (on which solr is based) is too complex for my requirement

Answer (score 1):

http://xapian.org/

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at System.Data.Sqlite, an ADO.Net wrapper around Sqlite. It's fully managed, simple to deploy (one dll), and includes the Sqlite FT3 search built-in, so you can use SQL to do the search.

http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com

http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html